# User (well, answerer) security on Stack Overflow

Tags: feature-request, answers, security

Earlier on I was perusing `python` questions, when I stumbled over a question - now deleted,  asking something along the lines:

> How can I access this website with Selenium? Why is the page blank when I open it?
> https://[website]

The URL looked dodgy enough, nonetheless, as I like to encourage intruders (and I foolishly consider myself unhackable, which is so wrong), I happily clicked it. As I somehow expected, page was blank. There was also some security certificate error. I looked up the JavaScript code on that page, but there wasn't anything spectacular.  I asked the user what he was trying to do with that page, collect users' IP addresses or something, and the question was quickly deleted (I screenshotted it, and the OP’s account as well).

There is a vast array of different programming domains, languages, languages' aspects and so on, and most answerers are likely specialized on their particular domain, not necessarily on security. There is a clear risk of them opening dangerous URLs, in their quest for a better reputation: you read the question and don't automatically think of any risks, but to the technical solution to that question.

How could this user's security loophole be mitigated? Maybe a discreet alert when the question contains a URL not belonging to a well known domain? Or a monthly security-awareness survey sent to users? Or automatically sanitizing questions? These could well be bad ideas, but the problem is real, and should be mitigated somehow. What do you think?

---

I'm probably driving on the opposite lane, but this question takes into consideration SO's system of reputation points and badges: this is a proper marketing system, cleverly designed around how dopamine hits and reward-seeking loops work, and it also takes into consideration human inability to multitask: when you're in the dopamine-hit loop and trying to find a way to solve that particular question, it's very easy to forget about security.

SO's marketing system **actively encourages you to interact with questions**, in order to create content which in turn translates into hard revenue for SO. Therefore, **shouldn't SO assume responsibility to remind you of possible dangers** in the very moment you interact with a question containing an unknown URL - or some minimal reproducible example which in order to reproduce, takes installing some obscure node packages which may contain malware?

---

I did not realize this is such a sensitive point. Also, at the point of writing this, the following comment has 15 upvotes:

> "How could this user' security loophole be mitigated?" - stop clicking
> links without taking measures to protect yourself –  Zoe stands with
> Ukraine Mod  4 hours ago

I get a sense of blindness, of mindlessness from the feedback I receive, be it comments or responses. Surely you understand, at least intuitively, how human mind works, and how the specific setup of SO Q&A discourages being security aware at the point of answering a question?

Comment: "How could this user' security loophole be mitigated?" - stop clicking links without taking measures to protect yourself

Comment: The question, for 10k users: https://stackoverflow.com/q/73260127/6296561

Comment: Regardless of the security risk, in the end, *someone* has to check the link, whether it's a regular user like us, a mod, or maybe even a CM/staff (very unlikely, but not impossible). And it's certainly not a unique issue in SO, or the rest of SE sites, but *the whole internet*.

Comment: Also, the page isn't blank. It does load some type of page that looks a suspicious lot like a blog (not enough content to tell if it's a forum, which is OPs claim. I also don't know turkish and can't be arsed to run it through a translator to check), at least when the traffic is routed via the UK. Doesn't appear to be malicious. The frontpage (read: no subdomains) does fail to load, but that appears to be a missing DNS entry or dead server. My browser errors out rather than showing a blank page anyway

Comment: I'm not invested enough in this forum to care, but maybe - just maybe - you should have paid more attention to my question and its implications, before down voting. It's about a user who wants to answer a question to gain more reputation, and - as humans have only a single language processor - he won't have anything else in mind apart from the technical aspects of the question, and his reputation points. So the risks are more acute than, say, other parts of the internet.   The page in question won't load until you add `www`, and accept the certificate error. It will load a standard Plesk serv.

Comment: Anyway, related feature request: [Should there be a warning before users leave a Stack Exchange site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/380796/241919)

Comment: "*It's about a user who wants to answer a question to gain more reputation, and - as humans have only a single language processor - he won't have anything else in mind apart from the technical aspects of the question, and his reputation points*" honestly, that's their own problem if they only care about reputation and ignoring the rest, even their own security/privacy.

Comment: Weren't URL shorteners banned for this reason?

Comment: This has been a problem since day 1. Isn't there some canonical meta post? Related: *[What happens to a user when he/she adds a malicious link into posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/294949/)*, *[Should this answer be deleted due to linking to (potentially) malicious content](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101318/)*, *[How do I report a user for having a potentially malicious URL on their profile?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/299572/)*, *[How should posts with malicious URLs be handled?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/288963/)*

Comment: cont' - *[Dealing with malicious links internally/externally](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251575/)*, *[A suggested edit cuts out allegedly malicious links. How do I safely check that claim and what review action do I take?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/328245/)*

Comment: Some URL shorteners were [blocked in 2017](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64450/ban-url-shortening-services/289658#289658).

Comment: None of you, esteemed people with 20k+ reputation I will deffo not strive to reach after this interaction, have stopped to consider the **frame of mind** of the answerer. It's not the same as visiting a random website, where you might have security in mind as well, but it's a special (marketing trap?) situation: there are points to be made, there is a technical situation to be solved, and already your attention span is overloaded.

Comment: I'm failing to see the problem still. Perhaps you should better explain the issue rather than rambling in the comments.

Comment: Well @NickstandswithUkraine, all the other commentators from above managed to see it, even the ones with immensely obnoxious replies, quickly followed by elitist replies. It's explained in plain English, I'm not sure how else I could explain it better. Maybe by joining the many, many Youtube videos about what SE has become these years, and debating this question?

Comment: No, I understand what you're asking, I fail to understand why it's a problem. You're on the Internet, take your security as seriously as you would anywhere on the Internet, why should SO do anything special?

Comment: Because of its very nature of Q&A, encouraged by a points-accruing system and a well crafted (marketing wise) badge accruing system: it **encourages** you to interact with the question, including any urls posted in that question. Therefore it should also assume responsibility and try to mitigate eventual security risks.

Comment: So? A search engine exists purely to link to stuff, and encourages you to click stuff. In fact, search engines go the extra mile; you go there with the intent of clicking stuff. Yet, scam ads and fraudulent results show up constantly, and are handled after the fact. That's what we do as well. Mass-educating people about the problem is something SO cannot be expected to do, because it's a wide-spread problem that should reach out to every user on the internet. Until then, we fight it after being posted, and thanks to Charcoal and other organized moderation efforts, and spam flags in general,

Comment: proper spam tends to be detected and deleted fairly fast. Also, there's already a lot of education and information around online safety. Not much to do about the problem when people ignore what they're taught or informed about, or fail to generalize or compare "this thing I've been educated about" to "that thing I just received on/via <platform>"

Comment: A search engine will not award you points and badges for interacting with its search results. The comparison is moot. It's not about general education, it's about a reminder in that *very* moment of you interacting with the question and having your mind full with something else than security aspects. It cannot be **that** hard to comprehend, you need a little mindfulness.

Comment: You go there to click links. By your own claims, "It's about a user who wants to answer a question to gain more reputation, and - as humans have only a single language processor - he won't have anything else in mind apart from the technical aspects of the question". Here, that transforms to "It's about a user who wants to click a link to solve a problem/find an answer/do something else, and - as humans [...] - they won't have anything else in mind but clicking".

Comment: If search engines are a different problem, then your arguments about why it's a problem on SO don't hold water. You can't have it both ways

Comment: Again: a search engine will not award you for clicking any links. That's why the comparison with them is moot, and because SO does award you points and badges for a content-creating activity which for SO means revenue, this particular problem is holding water.

Comment: While (most) search engines may not reward you with points or something else, rep on SO acts as a motivator. Most people go to search engines because they already have a motivation for finding something, and the effect of finding the right thing has roughly the exact same neurochemical response as gaining rewards in most cases. The comparison holds, your arguments do not

Comment: Also, in a lot of cases, the reward may not be from the search engine itself. You may already be attempting to solve another problem, [or settle a debate](https://xkcd.com/386/), or doing something else ending in an neurochemical and/or real-life/digital reward

Comment: If what you write would be true, then marketing departments and their high paid jobs (paid to create the exact dopamine-release scaffolds like SO's points & badges system) would be replaced by search engines. The discussion is not about search engines, so let's not hijack it in that direction.

Comment: All questions (and answers) on Stack Overflow/Stack Exchange are *required* to be self-contained. If you feel that a question isn't fully understandable without clicking a link to another page, then you should vote or flag for that question to be closed. There should *never* be a need for you to go to another site in order to fully understand the question or to get a complete answer. Question, and answer, authors can include links to other sites for more context, but SE/SO makes no representations as to how safe it will be to follow such links.

Comment: What you appear to be asking for here is for SO to present a popup that's basically an "Internet 101" tutorial any time someone tries to click an off-site link, which doesn't seem reasonable. While I certainly have concern for people following external links, I don't see how it's possible/reasonable for us to teach basic responsible internet usage to everyone. I'm sure that any attempt to do so will frustrate/piss-off a substantial quantity of people, particularly those who already know how to responsibly use the internet.

Comment: @Mayken, things are a bit more complex than what you appear to understand from them. As long as one uses marketing to actively encourage a dopamine-inducing activity, one should also feel responsible of the (lack of) security possible to arise from such activity. I cannot help feeling a sense of blindness, of mindlessness in the comments I receive.

Comment: It can be hard, but you have to accept that people can still be intelligent and just disagree with you. These comments about _blindness_, _mindlessness_, telling people it _can't be that hard to comprehend_, suggest you're not able/willing to do that at the moment, and it doesn't make for productive discourse

Comment: @Clive: Disagreement is one thing, groupthink and the over-decent dose of passive aggressiveness is another, coupled with intellectual dishonesty. The reaction of mods group was exactly as described in countless posts on Quora, Reddit, YT vids and other forums. It's like my question is blasphemic towards some sort of shrine, and no amount of logical reasons to even consider the fragility of human mind (induced by SO's marketing system) at the point of answering a question would suffice.

Comment: Yeah, or they just disagree with you

Comment: Oh - and stop clicking on stuff!

Answer (score 19):

Let me start with saying that a comment that states:

> I asked the user what he was trying to do with that page, collect users' IP addresses or something.

is unfriendly, if not harassment and that goes against the [Code of Conduct](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct). We all better steer clear of that.

If this was your first interaction with that user, assuming good intent would be better starting point. You can always switch to the opposite when evidence comes in. I do note the user has a filled about me and at least one other decent looking question. There is not a lot of signal to go into alert mode right from the start.

Now let's address the issue you raise. You or any one else is not required, ever, to visit any link that is present in user generated content. If you or any  one else chooses to do otherwise that is their call, just as they decided to click on a link that brought them to Stack Overflow.

If you feel a question or answer can only make sense when you click the link, ask the OP to include the needed details in their post. We have plenty of help center articles with guidance on that. Details can include a minimal working example, and/or clear code/steps to reproduce the issue. At best described in English and if the issue of visual nature a screenshot to support the text.

It is clear that true spammers or black-hat hackers would not be too eager to blow their cover, so that is when you have reason to raise some suspicion. Depending on how this evolves, votes of the down, close and delete kind can follow, if not red-flagging.

To address the questions you raised:

> How could this user's security loophole be mitigated?

We can't fix the internet. And even if we can today, in 6 to 8 weeks a decent link can go belly-up to a porn site.

> Maybe a discreet alert when the question contains a URL not belonging to a well known domain?

We already have that. [Smoke Detector](https://charcoal-se.org/smokey/) has a list of blocked domains and once a post appears on any site in the network Smokey posts a report in several chat rooms so users can investigate and take action when needed.

> Or a monthly security-awareness survey sent to users?

No.

> Or automatically sanitizing questions?

No. The filters SE has build over the years (pr0blam filter, your post contains only code) have proven to be inadequate to reach their goal. Only well meaning and unsuspecting users get tripped up by that non-sense.

> These could well be bad ideas, but the problem is real, and should be mitigated somehow. What do you think?

The problem is real ([it turns out I answered a similar question on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/380803)). Everyone should have a decent and up-to-date browser, anti-virus and a common understanding of how browsers work so they understand all risks, be it tracking, cookies, plugins or clicking dodgy links.

You closed with:

> SO's marketing system actively encourages you to interact with questions [...] Therefore, shouldn't SO assume responsibility to remind you of possible dangers

I don't see how asking users to build a body of knowledge all of a sudden gives Stack Exchange responsibility. We're not paid, hired or forced by SE to use this website or do anything their marketing geniuses come up with. We have very active community moderation that allows us, including yourself, to deal with post content in all sort of ways, thanks to Stack Exchange. We don't need features that put the responsibility back at a place where it is not best served. We're grown ups here and we don't need a babysitter. We need some sanity and trust.

That is not something Stack Overflow can solve with software. At best they could write and publish a blog post about it. I hear they take pitches for that.

Comment: You starting point is irrelevant: with less effort, your response falls under the very same sanctions (re-read it). This isn't about my non-sheltering comment to the user, but about a general problem of the site. Your response then continues to be plain wrong with 'You or any one else is not required, ever, to visit any link..'. Yes, you do need to follow most, if not all, to be able to respond properly. The end is a logical fallacy, intentionally ignoring the fact SO is making money from users' activity and generated content, encouraged by a marketing system.

Comment: I fail to see how the fact that an for-profit organization is running a website all of a sudden have to offer features to keep their users safe beyond what is reasonable. What is next? They have to send all of us a wire-less mouse because otherwise we might trip over its cord?